# Transitioning opacity from 0 to .9 works with toggling visibility from hidden to visible, but not the other way around

Tags: css, transition, visibility

I have a sub-menu that appears when I hover over an item in the main menu:

[image]

I have a transition effect whereby the sub-menu transitions from 0 opacity to .9 opacity in .5 seconds. However, I also have to toggle the visibility from hidden to visible in order for this to work.

Here's the html:

```
<li style="position: relative;" onmouseover="showLegalMenu()" onmouseout="hideLegalMenu()">
            <a>Legal</a>
                                            <div id="legal-menu" class="legal">
                                                <ul>
                                                    @if (termsOfUse != null)
                                                    {
                                                        <li><a href="@termsOfUse.Url">@termsOfUse.Name</a></li>
                                                    }
                                                    @if (privacyAndSecurity != null)
                                                    {
                                                        <li><a href="@privacyAndSecurity.Url">@privacyAndSecurity.Name</a></li>
                                                    }
                                                    @if (refundPolicy != null)
                                                    {
                                                        <li><a href="@refundPolicy.Url">@refundPolicy.Name</a></li>
                                                    }
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
    function showLegalMenu() {
        $("#legal-menu").addClass("legal-show");
    }

    function hideLegalMenu() {
        $("#legal-menu").removeClass("legal-show");
    }
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    .legal {
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #383838;
        opacity: 0;
        padding: 5px 0;
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 150px;
        transition: opacity .5s linear;
    }

    .legal-show {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: .9;
    }
```

Transitioning in works fine. The legal-show class is added, it is set to visible, and it transitions from 0 opacity to .9 opacity.

It's transitioning out that's the problem. The legal-show class is removed, causing the sub-menu to become invisible immediately (no transition). The sub-menu items still transition from .9 opacity to 0 opacity somehow (even though the div they are contained in is supposedly invisible at this time), but I would like for the sub-menu div to also transition to 0 opacity like this as well.

If I could just set the visibility to hidden at the end of the transition rather than right away, I believe this would work. How does one does this? Thanks.

Comment: dont use `visibility` instead use `height: 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to complicate it using JavaScript. This can be easily achieved by CSS only.

```css
.legal {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #383838;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.parent-li:hover .legal {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<li class="parent-li">
  <a>Legal</a>
  <div id="legal-menu" class="legal">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="@termsOfUse.Url">@termsOfUse.Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="@privacyAndSecurity.Url">@privacyAndSecurity.Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="@refundPolicy.Url">@refundPolicy.Name</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Nimsrules, this works flawlessly! What is the key factor that makes it work? My original problem was that visibility, being all or nothing, doesn't transition smoothly as opacity does. But you're not transitioning on visibility explicitly, you're transitioning on all. Is 'all' they key factor? How does this solve the problem?

Comment: `all` includes visibility and opacity both and the transition on opacity is what gives you the fadeToggle effect

Answer (score 0):

```css
.to-toggle {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: red;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}

.to-toggle.active {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="legal">
  <label id="hoverable">Hover me</label>
  <div class="to-toggle">
    <ul>
      <li>show1</li>
      <li>show2</li>
      <li>show3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(() => {
  $('#hoverable').hover(function() {
    $('.to-toggle').addClass('active')
    console.log('asdasd')
  }, function() {
    $('.to-toggle').css({'transition': 'opacity height 5s ease-out'}).removeClass('active')
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only transitionning *opacity*, do it also for *visibility* :

```
transition: opacity .5s linear, visibility .5s;
```

*visibility* is a "0" or "1" state (no intermediate values) so it will change its value after .5s, giving time for your *opacity* *transition* to take effect for the fade out.

**Edit** : for now I don't understand why it also work for the fade in.

```css
.legal {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #383838;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: opacity .5s linear, visibility .5s;
}

.legal-show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .9;
}

li.legal-container:hover #legal-menu,
#legal:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="position: relative;" class="legal-container">
    <a>Legal</a>
    <ul id="legal-menu" class="legal">

      <li><a href="@termsOfUse.Url">test3</a></li>

      <li><a href="@privacyAndSecurity.Url">test</a></li>

      <li><a href="@refundPolicy.Url">test2</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This would only shift the problem to fading in. Instead of seeing a smooth fade in as opacity moves from 0 to .9 over .5s, it would stay invisible until after .5 seconds after which the whole menu would suddenly appear.

Comment: Yes, looking back I agree with you. That being said the snippet seems to work in chrome and firefox (fade in and out).. i'll try to find an answer as to why it does.